# Apache Ignite Deployment on Open Shift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, ignite

We have observed following issue when we deploy Ignite Cluster on Open Shift

We have created respective PV and PVC YAML files.

One more important point is always it points to /ignite/work irrespective of Mount Path.

Error details at POD:
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Work directory does not exist and cannot be created: /ignite/work
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.convertException(IgniteUtils.java:1135)
at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:356)
at org.apache.ignite.startup.cmdline.CommandLineStartup.main(CommandLineStartup.java:365)
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Work directory does not exist and cannot be created: /ignite/work
at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.workDirectory(IgniteUtils.java:9900)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.initializeConfiguration(IgnitionEx.java:1891)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1715)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1160)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.startConfigurations(IgnitionEx.java:1054)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:940)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:839)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:709)
at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:678)
at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.start(Ignition.java:353)
... 1 more
Failed to start grid: Work directory does not exist and cannot be created: /ignite/work

---

YAML Content

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
annotations:
field.cattle.io/creatorId: user-zqf4l
creationTimestamp: "2021-01-12T06:48:02Z"
finalizers:

- kubernetes.io/pv-protection
  labels:
  cattle.io/creator: norman
  name: ignite-storage-work-vol
  resourceVersion: "18595579"
  selfLink: /api/v1/persistentvolumes/newsto
  uid: ee81855d-6497-4465-abdd-8244883e383b
  spec:
  accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
  storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
  ##when you create folder ensure you give proper permission to folder Assing Owner
  ##chown rootadmin:rootadmin grafana
  ##give full writes chmod 777 grafana/
  path: /opt/work ## Change the location before deploying
  type: ""
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  volumeMode: Filesystem

.....
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
name: ignite-storage-work-vol-claim
spec:
volumeName: ignite-storage-work-vol
accessModes:
- ReadWriteOnce
resources:
requests:
storage: 1Gi

......

## An example of a Kubernetes configuration for pod deployment.

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:

## Cluster name.

name: ignite-cluster
namespace: or
spec:

## The initial number of Ignite pods.

replicas: 2
serviceName: ignite-service
selector:
matchLabels:
app: ignite
template:
metadata:
labels:
app: ignite
spec:
serviceAccountName: ignite
# terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60000 (use in production for graceful restarts and shutdowns)
containers:
# Custom pod name.
- name: ignite-node
image: apacheignite/ignite:2.13.0
imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
env:
- name: OPTION_LIBS
value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http
- name: CONFIG_URI
value: file:///ignite/config/ignite-node-cfg.xml
- name: JVM_OPTS
value: "-DIGNITE_WAL_MMAP=false"
# consider this property for production -DIGNITE_WAIT_FOR_BACKUPS_ON_SHUTDOWN=true

```
      ports:
        # Ports you might need to open.
        - containerPort: 47100 # communication SPI port
        - containerPort: 47500 # discovery SPI port
        - containerPort: 49112 # JMX port
        - containerPort: 10800 # thin clients/JDBC driver port
        - containerPort: 8080 # REST API
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /ignite/config
          name: config-vol
        - name: work-vol
          mountPath: /tmp/work
          readOnly: false
        - name: storage-vol
          mountPath: /tmp/storage
          readOnly: false
        - name: wal-vol 
          mountPath: /tmp/wal
          readOnly: false
        - name: walarchive-vol     
          mountPath: /tmp/walarchive
          readOnly: false
        

  volumes:
    - name: config-vol
      configMap:
        name: ignite-cfg-persistent
    - name: work-vol
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: ignite-storage-work-vol-claim
    - name: storage-vol
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: ignite-storage-storage-vol-claim
    - name: wal-vol
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: ignite-storage-wal-vol-claim
    - name: walarchive-vol
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: ignite-storage-walarchive-vol-claim
```

Answer (score 2):

It's expecting to be able to write to `/ignite/work` but there's no persistent volume there. You appear to be mounting them in `/tmp`. Suggest changing:

```
- name: work-vol
  mountPath: /tmp/work
  readOnly: false
```

To:

```
- name: work-vol
  mountPath: /ignite/work
  readOnly: false
```

And the same for the other PVs.

Comment: Stpehen, Thnaks for providing suggestion. I have changed to /Ignite/work path but still same issue persists.   - name: work-vol
              mountPath: /ignite/work
              readOnly: false  Error is:   ... 1 more
Failed to start grid: Cannot read from work directory: /ignite/work

Comment: Thanks team for your support, issue is at ConfigMap and after correcting that issue has been fixed.